# Where can I learn about PHP internals?

Tags: php, php-internals

What are good resources to start learning the internals of PHP and the Zend Engine?

Comment: **One minute** breezethrough at http://www.phpbuilder.com/articles/application-architecture/optimization/php-and-zend-engine-internals.html

Answer (score 41, accepted):

The PHP Manual has a (sadly mostly empty) [chapter on PHP internals](http://www.php.net/manual/en/internals2.php).

The main development mailing list is internals@lists.php.net. You can [sign up via php.net](http://php.net/mailing-lists.php) and/or [use Markmail to search the archives](http://markmail.org/search/?q=list:net.php.lists.internals).

The git repository for PHP is located on [git.php.net](http://git.php.net/?p=php-src.git), but there is also a [mirror on GitHub](https://github.com/php/php-src).

For browsing the source code you should use the [lxr.php.net cross reference tool](http://lxr.php.net/).

The PHP wiki has a list of [various resources on PHP development](https://wiki.php.net/internals/references) (blog posts, books, slides, etc).

In particular there is an (older) book by [Sara Golemon](http://blog.golemon.com/): [Extending and Embedding PHP](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/067232704X).

A more current and ongoing effort is http://www.phpinternalsbook.com

If you have questions, you should try the #php.pecl room on efnet.

---

Also see this presentation by Sebastian Bergmann about Compiler Internals:

- http://www.scribd.com/doc/18171982/PHP-Compiler-Internals

And make sure to check Nikic's blog. He's got a number of posts on how to read the source:

- http://nikic.github.com/

In addition to that, you can check the PHP Credits for individual contributers:

- http://www.php.net/credits.php

A number of them run their own blogs which might contain more information.

Comment: aw i missed to see the link  (http://www.php.net/manual/en/internals2.php) , i have browsed into php docs assuming that is Zend Engine, not php, php and Zend Engine(server) ? are different, am i right?

Comment: @Adam The Zend Engine is the part that parses, compiles and executes PHP code. As opposed to the PHP core that is just a few basic things, like Request handling and File and Network I/O. On top of that you got the various extensions.

Comment: btw the book is at 2006 is it ok ?

Comment: @Adam didnt read it. Can't tell how much of that is still up-to-date today.

Comment: thanks alot gordon especialy the http://www.php.net/credits.php i never thought about that haha,anyway lets wait for 1-2 days :).

Comment: I found this quite useful: http://www.php-internals.com/book/ (use google translator if you can't read it ;)

Comment: @Gordon, I've a feeling Zend doesn't want to publish much writings on PHP internals to prevent [yet more](http://askubuntu.com/a/653637/344328) soon-to-be competitors.

Comment: @Pacerier your feelings are yours.

Comment: @Gordon i found this resources and i think it's pretty useful too, https://www.scribd.com/document/49306684/building-custom-php-extensions , https://www.kchodorow.com/blog/2011/08/11/php-extensions-made-eldrich-installing-php/ , https://derickrethans.nl/talks/extensions-phpnw11.pdf

Answer (score 7):

Another lecture on *"how does it work"* theme:

**PHP UK Conference 2012** <sup>[playlist](http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLE757588AF8F4CA53&feature=plcp)</sup> **- [PHP under the hood](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bxxIXPc9IR8)** <sup>[slides](http://schlueters.de/presentations/#p=20120225_phpuk_php_under_the_hood&n=0)</sup>, by Johannes Schlüter

Answer (score 2):

On
http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/weblinux2/php/ch14_01.htm
you can also find some interesting internals about writing php extensions

Answer (score 1):

From Dutch PHP Conference (2009):

[PHP Compiler Internals](http://techportal.inviqa.com/2010/02/02/php-compiler-internals/) (mp3)

with slides:

http://www.scribd.com/doc/18171982/PHP-Compiler-Internals