# Good in-depth technical documentation on PHP

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [where can i learn php internals, how they work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4389738/where-can-i-learn-php-internals-how-they-work)

Are there any good resources for really in depth technical details on php, i.e. the nuts a bolts of how it works.

Most resources don't go beyond actually how to use the language.  Im interested in finding out what goes on below it all (from a high level perspective i.e. i dont want to  sit a read the c code :) )

Comment: this might help : http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bxxIXPc9IR8

Comment: I'm perplexed as to the downvoting.

Comment: @BenBarden I didn't downvote but one could consider this question not-useful because of the dupe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would start with the [internals section](http://www.php.net/manual/en/internals2.php) of the PHP Manual.

There's also an [internals page](https://wiki.php.net/internals) in the PHP Wiki.